# How do I deploy the Visual C++ Runtime 2010 in the bin library of a web application?

Tags: runtime, web-deployment, visual-c++-2010, chilkat, appharbor

I am trying to deploy a web project that uses a specific library (in this case Chilkat) to a web host (appharbor.com). The problem is the library needs the Visual Studio C++ 2010 runtime (http://www.cknotes.com/?p=311). My question is how do I deploy that runtime correctly?

**1. Choice of deployment method**

On my local development machine the runtime is installed but I only have git push access to the hosting environment.

Based on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235316%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) there are three options to deploying the runtime:

1. Use the redistributable package
   (recommended)
2. Use Merge Modules (requires administrative rights)
3. Deploy with the application

Option 3 is the only one I can do with this host since I don't have administrative access to the server.

**2. Determining which dlls should be deployed**

The MSDN page states that the dlls should be in "Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\Redist". In my case the Redist directory does not exist at that location (running on 64-bit, so I checked both "Program Files" and "Program Files (x86)").

I unzipped the redistributable package and the vs_red.cab inside that to find a list of dlls that are contained:
 - atl100
 - mfc100 (+ language variants)
 - mfc100u
 - msvcp100
 - msvcr100
 - vcomp100
 - msdia71

At the same time I checked the library in reflector to see what is was referencing:
 - Microsoft.VisualC (.net)
 - KERNEL32.dll (native)
 - MSVCR100.dll (native)
 - ... and one mysterious library without a name. Shows up as module with empty text.

Side note: the chilkat library used here is available in x64 and x86 versions. I performed these tasks with the x86 only because the target system seems to be x86. (Deploying x64 leads to a "An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format." error.)

**3. Finding the dlls to deploy**

The dlls in the unzipped vc_red.cab where named incorrectly so I decided to find the dlls on the hard disk. Searching for atl100 revealed three location: system32, syswow64 and as part of an application directory.

All files mentioned above were in system32 except:
- msdia71 (native) - This has to do with debugging and is not on my disk at all, so I'm assuming it is not needed.
- Microsoft.VisualC (.net) - Found this in GAC in the correct version (10.x).

(I did not copy KERNEL32.dll because this is a Windows built-in library.)

**4. Adding libraries to project**

The VisualC .net library was added as a reference. The native libraries were added to the root of my web application and properties set to "Build Action: Content" and "Copy to Output: Always". Once built the dlls appeared next to the .net libraries in the bin folder as expected.

But when I deploy and run I get the error message:
Could not load file or assembly '' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found.

You can see the [build output of the project here](http://pastebin.com/cB7YP90A) and I can observe that the dlls I think are required are being copied to the output directory, but still there a mistake somewhere. Anybody have an idea? Or a better approach at debugging this? Or am I doing something stupid :)?

Comment: I have this exact same issue (5 years later).. how did you resolve?

Comment: Unfortunately I never did. Used a managed library instead.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I hate to say anything is impossible, but...

Answer (score 0):

Some options I see:

- contact hoster support to install VC++ on the server
- contact Chilkat support
- deploy on a local server and turn on Fusion
  (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4(v=vs.80).aspx)

Comment: Excellent suggestions, thanks. We were going with GoDaddy, or as I like to call them NoGoDaddy.... ;-) and they were having no part of it.. FYI If you want to do MVC or C# avoid NoGoDaddy as they don't "really" support it, no matter what they say on their site... Azure is awesome... AWS is supposedly great also...

Answer (score 0):

You can add the dlls to the root project.
Then, click on each dll -> click properties -> set  'Build Action': Content, and set 'copy to output Directory': Copy Always.

Now build, and check your bin. dlls are there.

I used this way as adding to references as existing items and browsing the dlls gave some errors that cannot load dll.

I liked to group the dlls in a folder and then have them in bin with no parent folder, but could not get to that yet.